# modal button to display images in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, modal-dialog, assets

In my project I want to show images when I click the button. How I can configure the method openModal() on (click) to do this?

The IMG are taken from assets directory, and change based on your code (B1, B2) choice.

```html
<!-- OPERATION -->
  <div class="card my-5">
    <div class="card-header" style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">
      <p><strong>Operation</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <tr *ngFor="let arr of varOperation; index as i">
            <td>
              Code: {{arr.operation.code}}
              - {{arr.operation.description}}
            </td>
            <button style="margin-left: 20px; float: right;" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="viewCodeOperation(arr.operation.code)" (click)="openModal()">
              Go
            </button>
          </tr>
        </div>  
      </form> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- IMAGES -->
  <div class="overflow-auto">
    <div *ngIf="imgB1">
      <img src="assets\images\B1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="imgB2">
    <img src="assets\images\B2.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
viewCodeOperation(code: string) {
    this.imgB1 = false
    this.imgB2 = false

    console.log(code)
    if(code == "B1"){
      this.imgB1 = true
    }
    else if(code == "B2"){
      this.imgB2 = true
    }
}

  openModal() {
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a library like this https://github.com/maximelafarie/ngx-smart-modal one to set up modals in angular.